# jQuery window scroll event does not fire up

Tags: jquery, window, scroll

I'm trying to implement a simple "stay inside the viewport" behaviour to a div via jquery. For that i need to bind a function to the scroll event of the window, but i can't seem to get it to fire up: nothing happens. I've tried a simple alert(), console.log() no dice. An idea what i'm doing wrong?

This code :

```
$(window).scroll(function () {  
            console.log("scrolling");           
});
```

sits in script.js, located at the very bottom of my html file

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**
Test URL: http://pixeline.eu/test/menu.php

Comment: Is the content of the page long enough? Works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/x5NzM/ If there is no content that can be scrolled, the `scroll` event won't be raised.

Comment: your example page is binding to `$(document).scroll` try `$(window).scroll`

Comment: it seems that the the scroll not triggering has something to do with the way your using the css, am doing some tests now.

Comment: Also finding that having `overflow-x` on the body tag caused the scroll events to not fire either! Reproduced in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @BU0 I have also found that to be the case ( in fact your comment just solved a perplexing problem I was having). Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you're calling your script below jquery cdn.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Your CSS is actually setting the rest of the document to not show overflow therefore the document itself isn't scrolling. The easiest fix for this is bind the event to the thing that is scrolling, which in your case is `div#page`.

So its easy as changing:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {  // OR  $(window).scroll(function() {
    didScroll = true;
});
```

to

```
$('div#page').scroll(function() {
    didScroll = true;
});
```

Comment: Ok, so what generally one should pay attention to when designing a page like the one from the opening post? Are there more cases that can trigger such problems?

Comment: wow man u made my day . been stuck on this problem the whole day . div#pageUp in my case works great! . time for a cigar

Comment: brilliant! I had a similar problem with an offcanvas nav

Comment: The problem for me was html, body {
    height: 100%; ... } this caused the scrolling not to work (default in a grails app)

Comment: saved my day!! been stuck with this for a while. the problem in my case was `body{ height: 100vh; }` thanks!

Comment: All this because I had overflow: hidden on the HTML tag! Thanks!

Comment: This answer is magical! I have no idea why this happens but you are a champ man.

Answer (score 39):

My issue was I had this code in my css

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Once I removed it, the scroll event on window fired again

Comment: I had the same problem here. Looks like the `scroll` event doesn't handles well an element with css `overflow`. That was bugging even animations with `scrollTop`... Thanks for sharing!

Comment: For future reference, trying to use materializecss's pushpin component (http://materializecss.com/pushpin.html), in my case, wasn't working because of height:100% on html and body as well!

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#div').scroll(function () {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight-1) {

     //fire your event


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution is:

```
 $('body').scroll(function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To whom its just not working to (like me) no matter what you tried: 
`<element onscroll="myFunction()"></element>`
 works like a charm

exactly as they explain in W3 schools
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onscroll.asp

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seemd to work for me, but this did the trick

```
$(parent.window.document).scroll(function() {
    alert("bottom!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case you should put the function in `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div#page').on('scroll', function () {
     ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

1. Declare your `jQuery` between `<script>` and `</script>` in the `<head>`,
2. Wrap your `.scroll()` event within

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //do something
});
```

Comment: nope, does not work either. will put the link online so you guys can see it (not) happening.