# On Scroll down how to make ajax call and get the respone data

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

Please can you people guide me how to make ajax call when scroll down

Comment: SCROLL down triigers a funtion of ajax when reach bottom of page in that footer is reoved it should trigger before footer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var no=1;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if(no==1)
    {
        if ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()) {
            no=2;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "request.php",
                data: datas,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){

                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This does an ajax call when a user reaches at end of page.

You can specify a height at which it occurs.

Comment: hey raghav can you tell me what does cache does in this

Comment: it tells whether to make a local copy of the data received from ajax call.

Comment: hey raghav , i want to ask this funtion scroll down call once when window size if once done it shuld not call again again when ever this scroll down on it

Comment: not this one, i mean to ask is ajax call when no data is prest how can i stop the ajax call and another qution is how can i remove the footer from this height which is calculated .

Comment: <div class="head">
</div>
<div class="center">
<div class="trigger-scroll">see more</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a separate stack overflow question about firing events on scrolling:

[jQuery window scroll event does not fire up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686629/jquery-window-scroll-event-does-not-fire-up)

And here is jquery's manual that shows how to use ajax:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Combine and enjoy!