# element bind in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

```
var scrollheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollHeight');
```

I want to do something like above, without using jquery. I came across that I can use knockoutjs element bind - `data-bind="element: scrollbox"`

But I am not sure how to do it

Comment: Are you wanting to bind the attribute `scrollHeight` to a value in another element?

Comment: no. I want to make an ajax call to fetch more contents when the scroll height gets increased

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in KO? It's more for data-binding than event handling. `$(window).scroll(...)` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that, from reading your comments, KnockOutJS isn't the best candidate in your case for handling ajax on scrolling.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687978/on-scroll-down-how-to-make-ajax-call-and-get-the-respone-data) handles the `window.scroll(...)` function and makes an `ajax` call.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, ko does not have its own built-in element binding. I created one that I use in a couple of projects, looks like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.element = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var name = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        viewModel[name] = element;
    }
};
```

However, when binding, I put the viewmodel property name in quotes, something like `data-bind="element: 'elementName'"`. The viewmodel would then look like this:

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.elementName = undefined;
    self.doSomething = function() {
        $(self.elementName).fadeOut();
    };
}
```

Keep in mind that `self.elementName` will remain `undefined` until after `ko.applyBindings` executes. So you should really only use this in click or other event bindings that execute as functions after the viewmodel is bound.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.scrollTo = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        jQuery(element).show().focus();
        if (jQuery(element).position() != null) {
          jQuery(window).scrollTop(jQuery(element).position().top);
        } 
    }    
};
```

and use it in HTML:

```
data-bind="scrollTo: {}
```