# MVC3 How to implement result browser like twitter/facebook do it (without paging)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm looking for leads on how to implement a (search-)result browser without using paging. But more like how twitter/facebook do it.

At first only 10 or so results need to be displayed but when scrolling down, more results (if any) should be added asynchronously. I've found examples with a [more] button at the end but I would like the browser to automatically fetch more when the bottom of the pane is reached.

I'm having trouble finding the right examples. Probably because I don't know what keywords to google on...

Hope you can help me out in the right direction!

Kind regards,

Paul

Comment: You will probably need to use a bit of jquery to call your ajax when the user scrolls down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advise you read following article regarding this subject:

- [Infinite Scroll in ASP.NET MVC](http://tpeczek.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/infinite-scroll-in-aspnet-mvc.html)

There is also a sample application available [here](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/86969).

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [Replace paging with jQuery and subsonic continuous scrolling method](http://blog.solutionrevolution.net/replace-paging-with-jquery-and-subsonic-conti) blog post.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following pages:

[On Scroll down how to make ajax call and get the respone data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687978/on-scroll-down-how-to-make-ajax-call-and-get-the-respone-data)

[create-a-dynamic-scrolling-content-box-using-ajax](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/create-a-dynamic-scrolling-content-box-using-ajax/)

I believe that should help you!