# Why doesn't my window scroll event fire up at all. Other answers did not solve

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[**Complete SSCCE on JSFiddle here!**](http://jsfiddle.net/3LcfL5wa/)

I am trying to fire-up a `JQuery` event to add a `class` to a `div`, and add some inline style *(i.e. a value for `top` location offset)* when the user scrolls down the page to a certain value of `scrollTop()` *(i.e. when the number of pixels scrolled down (i.e. `scrollTop()`) becomes greater than the viewport height)*

But the JQuery event does not seem to fire-up at all.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    ...
});
```

***What I tried:***

From my [SO search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686629/jquery-window-scroll-event-does-not-fire-up), I gathered that the thing we bind the event to must not be set to not show *overflow*. My background image slideshow is `position:fixed;`. So I also tried `$("div.firstPage").bind(...` and `$("div.header-menu-container-nav").bind(...` but to no avail.

***Note:*** I know that the example in the JSFiddle might look a little complex. But that is what shows complete CSS (and markup), so I did not try to simplify it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax errors in these locations: (The class names are not enclosed in quotes.)

```
if (currentPosition >= vph) {
        alert("Condition met!"); //check

        $('.header-menu-container-nav').addClass('sticky');
        --^                       ---^
        $('.header-menu-container-nav').css('top',(deltaMenuPosition)+'px');
        --^                       ---^
        $('.header-menu-container-nav').fadeIn()
        --^                       ---^
    }
```